# How to exclude first cell of the active cells of a column while comparing the values of the cells of the column with a string

Tags: vba, excel, cells

How to exclude the first cell of the column C i,e the header
[image]

```
Sub test()

Dim MySht As Worksheet
    Dim MyRng As Range

    Set MySht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set MyRng = MySht.UsedRange.Columns("C")

    For Each cell In MyRng.Cells

        If Not cell = "test"  Then
           cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to skip row 1 of the range. In that case you could modify your for loop as follows:

```
For Each cell In MyRng.Cells
    If cell.Row != 1 Then
        If Not cell = "test"  Then
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks Nick.Works perfectly for me.